# Git LPass: Could not find specified account

Tags: git, lastpass

I'm trying to use **lastpass-cli** on fedora 24 to log git without entering password every push/pull.
But I received this error below:

> Error: Could not find specified account(s).
>
> Error: Could not find specified account(s).
>
> Couldn't find host in lastpass DB.
>   error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass'

Into lastpass vault I have tried both configuration:

1) code.xyz.com/project/example.git (more specific)

2) Just code.xyz.com

I'm using this script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lastpass/lastpass-cli/master/contrib/examples/git-credential-lastpass

And then the configuration:

```
git config --global credential.helper './git-credential-lastpass'
```

Any clue, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering with the script I found a solution:
Use the hostname of the repo (without protocol and with port if it's not set to default default) as the Name property of the LastPass credential.

For example if your remote origin url is:

```
url = https://username@repo.example.com:12345/reponame
```

then set the name of the LastPass credential to:

```
repo.example.com:12345
```